# Broadcast data to nearby android/IOS devices without any kind of networking

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi

I want to broadcast data from an Android or IOS device over the air (with WiFi or Bluetooth for example) without necessarily being on a network.

What I want to do :

- smartphone A is constantly broadcasting data packets over the air.
- smartphone B is constantly looking for packets.
- When B recognize a valid packet he can get the content.

A data packet will be something like this :
[packet_header][packet_length][data][packet_footer]

I know that I can use Bluetooth friendly name to broadcast a small amount of data but 248 bytes (which is available data length with this technology) isn't enough for my needs.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Yes there is. I can confirm that it's possible on android. Please google "run web socket server on android", you should find something.

Comment: I may be wrong but web socket need a network to works, isn't it ?

Comment: You are over Wifi right?

Comment: Yes but I want that device A may be on is own network (like connected to his box to get internet) and smartphone B may be on another one or no network at all and B still able to see packet sent by A. I am currently using wifi Direct on Android which is P2P network but it is working only on Android and it is networking... I am wondering if I can just send packet over wifi (like beacons)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your'e looking for is [Nearby](https://developers.google.com/nearby/). Nearby Connections is a peer-to-peer networking API that allows apps to easily discover, connect to, and exchange data with nearby devices in real-time, regardless of network connectivity.

Hope it helps.